# Read a source file for a custom ant task

Tags: java, io, classloader

I want to open a source file for my custom ant task. I thought this would be easy, because surely the class loader get resource would immediately find the source file for me. Wrong!

Here's my code:

```
//build the name of the template
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(VersionTemplate.class.getName());
sb.append(".java");
String templateName = sb.toString();
//find the template
InputStream inputStream = VersionTemplate.class.getResourceAsStream(templateName);
```

inputStream is always null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred to me after the fact that getResource() looks on the class path, which is not where the source code is. I ended up simply just coding a relative path to the code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   templateName = templateName.replaceAll(".","/");
   InputStream inputStream = VersionTemplate.class.getClassLoader().
                              getResourceAsStream(templateName);
```

Please make sure ".java" file is present in the same package as compile ".class" files.

Comment: This changed nothing. What do you mean by using the absolute path? Shouldn't the way that I built the template name return the file accessible by the class loader?

Comment: Look at the source code. Everything you should need is there.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked. **I updated the answer** after trying myself. This is working. Please try at your end.